# Docker: how to fix "Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting"

Tags: docker, boot2docker, pull

I have a fresh install using boot2docker.  (DockerToolbox was giving me the same error.  After uninstalling DockerToolbox, I deleted ~/.docker and searched my whole filesystem for anything starting with "docker" and found no other configuration files where things might be hiding.)

This is the second command I did, after `docker run hello-world`:

```
bash-3.2$ docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
6071b4945dcf: Verifying Checksum 
5bff21ba5409: Pulling fs layer 
e5855facec0b: Download complete 
8251da35e7a7: Download complete 
8251da35e7a7: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
```

And I'm stuck here indefinitely.

I promise I only have 1 docker process running.  I just want to get past this.  If it means nuking whatever cache is in place and doing a manual download, that's okay.  I just want to stop being stuck here for hours.

Comment: Related: [Error on Docker Pull - "Layer already being pulled by another client"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32183390)

Answer (score 6):

You need to restart Docker service or just restart the OS.
Also in this [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3115) @avramirez pointed out that you can do this using boot2docker:

```
boot2docker stop
boot2docker up

docker pull <repo>
```

Comment: I rebooted the host computer, and then ran your commands.  I still get the "8251da35e7a7: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting" response.

Comment: Did you try restarting the Docker daemon? It worked for me.

Comment: I even did "boot2docker destroy; boot2docker init" in between the 'stop' and 'up.' This is OSX so docker is inside VirtualBox.

Comment: Ah, doing that *within* the VM seems to have cleared the logjam.  I might have to do this repeatedly but I am at least moving forward!

Answer (score 2):

quote from [issue#15603](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15603) message:

> Hello all! I believe this should by fixed on master by #15489 (and
>   will soon ship in a few weeks as part of Docker 1.9.0).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Docker.

Try out the following in order (Trying to avoid restarting the OS):

1. `ps aux | grep docker-compose` and find the PID of `docker-compose` processes running.
   Kill them using `kill <pid>`
2. Restart Docker using `service docker restart` (linux)
3. 2nd method should ideally solve the problem, if not, Restart the OS.

Hopefully, this issue will be solved in version 1.9