# Error on Docker Pull - "Layer already being pulled by another client"

Tags: docker, pull

I'm new to docker and have followed the installation instructions on their site [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/).

The installation completed successfully:

```
docker -v
Docker version 1.8.1, build d12ea79
```

but when I try to run

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

I get the following:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world

535020c3e8ad: Pulling fs layer 
af340544ed62: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting. 
af340544ed62: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.
```

This then continues to hang indefinitely.

I have tried restarting the service and my entire machine. I always get the same problem.

Any idea what's causing this or how to resolve?

Comment: looks like the same problem as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017719/docker-how-to-fix-layer-already-being-pulled-by-another-client-waiting

Comment: @ThomasLang - I read that one earlier. Unfortunately my problem is slightly different. I'm running docker locally on a Ubuntu machine rather than inside a VM. I'm also not receiving the "e5855facec0b: Download complete" outputs.

Comment: try restarting docker: sudo restart docker

check if any containers are listed docker ps -a

Comment: just tried both. No containers are listed after using docker ps -a

Comment: This is a really annoying error and I've seen it in Docker workshops around the world. More details at: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have now resolved itself. Quite possibly it was caused by a problem at docker's end.

Answer (score 2):

This command helped on my end on Ubuntu 14.04 (`Docker version 1.8.1, build d12ea79`):

```
sudo restart docker
```

Comment: I tried that when I encountered this problem. Still got the same issue. Since it fixed itself later on that day I'm assuming the problem was connecting to the dockerhub registry properly.

Comment: This solution helped me--in my case a download had been interrupted when I moved my laptop.